# Visual Studio wont let me remove the maximise/minimise button/icon etc

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have Form1.cs which I have set in properties to be borderless, without an icon, max/min buttons (and the changes are shown visually in Form1.cs), but when I debug/run, all of those controls stay the same as they previously were.  The properties are then found in my code under  private void InitializeComponent() as  this.ShowIcon = false; etc.. Form1.Designer.cs is always empty though, have I messed up some settings somehow that overrides my form1.cs selections?

Comment: What OS are you running this on ?

Comment: If I have understood your requirement correctly you want a WinForm without min/max icons

Comment: Did you do a cross-reference on this.ShowIcon to see if it is written to in more than one place?

Comment: How do I do that Gerhard? Im on windows 7 Russ.  @HatSoft, I want to make a lot of changes to the settings, but as I say none of them I make actually seem to take effect when running the program.

Comment: The place that all the changes get stored will be Form.Designer.cs try looking in that please

Comment: ok in form.designer.cs I have no code at all, not a single line, its just a blank page.

Comment: interesting... does you code compile? if yes what do you see when you run it in debug mode

Comment: Yes, I just tested it and it compiles to release/bin folder and runs as it does when in debug mode- its a window holding a directx control that I am drawing to. Again though, unfortunately the various controls I set to FALSE are still there as if set to TRUE ;(

Comment: EDIT: It works now, but I have to cut/paste all of the properties from initialise components to mainClass(). So annoying! (BTW, any idea how to make the now transparent form clickthrough?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the forms .MaximizeBox and .MinimizeBox to false ?

If so, can you please post the contents of that InitializeComponent method.

Comment: Certainly!         private void InitializeComponent()
             {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // MainClass
            // 
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 272);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.Name = "MainClass";
            this.ShowIcon = false;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            this.TopMost = true;
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

Answer (score 1):

Winforms have properties like MinimizeBox, MaximizeBox and ShowIcon on the designer if you set then to False. Then you wont require any line of code in private void InitializeComponent()

Comment: Yes, I am not setting these manually in code, I am doublclicking the relevant boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Design view only show what is set in Form1.Design.cs, and not your custom code (except for some events and properties like resize...) Did you overwrite any design values in your code after you run InitializeComponents?

The easiest way is to cross-reference Form1.

Comment: I honestly dont know if I did overwrite anything, I did make some cut/paste jobs for something else but don't think I took anything out.  If I delete the things from my initialisation method, and then go back to the form and double click all the controls settings I want, they appear straight away in my initialisation method again as this.   this.ShowIcon = false; etc..

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to remove the entire title bar you'll want to set the FormBorderStyle to None. If that doesn't work try and set a breakpoint after your form has loaded and check the values to make sure they are what you think they should be. This should not require any coding.